# Sync PostgreSQL and Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I had a legacy database which I uploaded to PostgreSQL and connected it with Django. Then, I changed DB with running SQL scripts directly in the PostgreSQL (I deleted few columns), then manually deleted few columns in django models.py. Since then, I cannot make any migrations, whenever I try it, Django is trying to delete the column which I manually deleted, and gives the error below. How do I sync my DB and Django project so that I can make modifications to the project?

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "confidence" of relation "Location" does not exist
```

EDIT:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
D:\projects\map\dataXProject
(0.328)
            SELECT
                c.relname,
                CASE
                    WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p'
                    WHEN c.relkind IN ('m', 'v') THEN 'v'
                    ELSE 't'
                END
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('f', 'm', 'p', 'r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        ; args=None; alias=default
(0.250) SELECT "django_migrations"."id", "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name", "django_migrations"."applied" FROM "django_migrations"; args=(); alias=default        
(0.235) 
            SELECT
                c.relname,
                CASE
                    WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p'
                    WHEN c.relkind IN ('m', 'v') THEN 'v'
                    ELSE 't'
                END
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('f', 'm', 'p', 'r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        ; args=None; alias=default
(0.343) SELECT "django_migrations"."id", "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name", "django_migrations"."applied" FROM "django_migrations"; args=(); alias=default        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
(0.281) 
            SELECT
                c.relname,
                CASE
                    WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p'
                    WHEN c.relkind IN ('m', 'v') THEN 'v'
                    ELSE 't'
                END
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('f', 'm', 'p', 'r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        ; args=None; alias=default
  Applying sites.0008_remove_location_approved_remove_location_confidence_and_more...ALTER 
TABLE "Location" DROP COLUMN "approved" CASCADE; (params ())
(0.718) ALTER TABLE "Location" DROP COLUMN "approved" CASCADE; args=(); alias=default
ALTER TABLE "Location" DROP COLUMN "confidence" CASCADE; (params ())
(0.328) ALTER TABLE "Location" DROP COLUMN "confidence" CASCADE; args=(); alias=default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "confidence" of relation "Location" does not exist 


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\map\dataXProject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\projects\map\dataXProject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 290, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 131, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 163, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 248, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 131, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 170, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 683, in remove_field
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 192, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "confidence" of relation "Location" does not exist
```

Comment: There should be a table in your Postgres DB called `django_migrations`, take note of the existing entries and create a new 1 that looks like the migration you are trying to run.. this will make Django think that it's already ran it

Comment: Please post the complete error stack trace to give some more details so we can help you more clearly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use migrations even for running custom SQL. This would prevent such situations.

However, you can skip a single migration, if the changes are already applied to your database, using the `--fake` flag for `./manage.py migrate`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake

If this is no option, you could add a column named `confidence` to you `Location` table using direct SQL commands. Your migration will then delete this column to get you in sync with the model database graph.